# Switching to Ruby 1.9.3 from Ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby, heroku

I tried to run the ruby installer for 1.9.3 on my windows 8.1 desktop but it returns the error

```
"Setup was unable to create the director "C:\Program Files(x86)\Heroku\ruby-19.3"

Error 5: Access is denied
```

Comment: try to install it somewhere else

Comment: also try to upgrade using pik (https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) the windows equivalent of rvm

Comment: run the `cmd` or `installer` as administrator and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your console with full privileges. Right-click on the program before entering and select "Run as administrator." After that you should be able to use that console session to install Ruby wherever you like.